# MySQL Query for Location without using Spatial

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have this table:

```
activity - activity_id - (INT) PRIMARY, 
            item_id (INT),
            user_id (INT)
            lat (FLOAT), 
            lng (FLOAT), 
            created_at (DATETIME)
```

I'd like to run the following query:

```
SELECT item_id, count(distinct user_id) as c_c
FROM activity
WHERE (lat BETWEEN X and X and lng BETWEEN X and X)
and created_at >= DATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
GROUP by item_id
ORDER by c_c desc
LIMIT 10
```

I thought that I did an index on the following fields:

```
lat,
lng,
created_at,
bid
```

That - it would run really fast, but it still runs slow. What is the optimal index here? Do I did to include user_id in there?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

Here is the EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |  table   | type  |              possible_keys              |   key   | key_len | ref  | rows  |                    Extra                     |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | activity | index | lat,created_lat_lng,created_at,lat_user | item_id |       4 | NULL | 51510 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Indexes on the table:

```
+-----------------+----------------------+
|      Name       |       Columns        |
+-----------------+----------------------+
| lat             | lat, lng             |
| created_lat_lng | lat, lng, created_at |
| created_at      | created_at           |
| lat_user        | lat,lng,user_id,item |
| item_id         | item_id              |
+-----------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Add the EXPLAIN result of the query please, you have those indexes created?

Comment: It shouldn't be slow with 51510 rows, just for testing, if you remove: `and created_at >= DATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)` do the speed (index usage) improve? I don't understand why it doesn't use the lat,lng index.
You dont need the parenthesis on `(lat BETWEEN X and X and lng BETWEEN X and X)`

Comment: It doesn't help, if i drop it takes 5 seconds to query - and thats when I force it to use the (lat_user) index.